# Does Sitecore Search JS SDK support visitor context in widget rules?

Tags: sitecore-search

I have got a test solution created from [Sitecore Search JS SDK Starter Kit](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Search-JS-SDK-Starter-Kit). Basic search and filtering functionality works correctly and now I want to configure additional widget rules based on visitor context.

I followed [this documentation page](https://doc.sitecore.com/search/en/users/search-user-guide/work-with-widget-variations-and-rules.html) for setting up a simple rule that should be applied when a page URL includes a specific UTM parameter. This is how the rule looks in CEC:

[image: Visitor context of the widget rule]

However, I can't make it work with my test Search front-end, the rule does not seem to be triggering. I've checked the API request headers and payload, and can't see any of the attributes that are available for selection in the UI (UTM parameters, FB click ID, app type, etc). So I'm not sure if some configuration is missing or it is not supported by Search JS SDK.

Has anybody managed to set up a rule with visitor context and connect it to a front-end website with Sitecore Search JS SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussed this with Sitecore Search team and it's been confirmed that the visitor context parameters are not supported yet. However, it is in the roadmap, and the team is working on it, so I'll update the answer once this feature is fully released.